# Rendering Artifacts in Stacked Area Chart with Gaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create an area chart of multiple series with percentual stacking using Hichstock. The time series may contain gaps which I want to visualize using the `gapSize` option.

When I render the chart with `stacking: 'percent'`, [the gaps are not fully empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Sc5.png). However, there is no issue when rendered with `stacking: 'normal'`.

Is there any option or incompatibility that I am not aware of, or is this likely a bug in Highstock?

Here is a JSFiddle that illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8d5qzwrg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug in highcharts, a workaround is to use [`step`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.step), like this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'percent',
    gapSize: 1,
    step: 'center'
  }
},
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/0rdjL1gq/2/